# It is possible to orthogonalize a set of linearly independent vectors via SVD?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, orthogonality

Let's say I have a set of linearly independent vectors, collected in a square matrix $\mathbf{M}$.

I know that I could orthogonalize these vectors with the QR decomposition,

$\mathbf{M} = \mathbf{QR}$

where $\mathbf{Q}$ is my orthogonal set of vectors.

I'm curious if it is possible to do the same with the SVD, but I cannot figure out how.

I want to know how to go from $\mathbf{M}$ to $\mathbf{Q}$, using SVD instead of QR.

If this is not possible, I'd like to know as well.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding what you are trying to say, but if the vectors that form $M$ are orthonormal, then that doesn't mean the singular values are all 1

Comment: Not only that but for $E$ to be the identity matrix, $M$ must be square

Comment: @texasflood Sorry, I am assuming M is square!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $M$ is a matrix of $k$ linearly independent columns with SVD $M = U \Sigma V^H$, then the first $k$ columns of $U$ form an orthonormal basis for the span of the columns of $M$.

Comment: Would that mean that, if I performed both an SVD and a QR decomposition on M, Q and U would be the same? I don't think so, so I want to know how to go from U to Q, or if that is possible? Maybe I'm looking for how to use U in a change of basis procedure?

Comment: $Q$ and $U$ will not generally be the same, but they should do all the same things.

Answer (score 1):

If $E$ is full rank (and it will be if $M$ is square and full rank), you can take the square root of it

$$UEV^H$$
$$=UE^{1/2}IE^{1/2}V^H$$

And so you can just absorb $E^{1/2}$ into $U$ and $V$.

It should go without saying that this is no longer a singular value decomposition and may lose all the nice properties SVD enjoys.

Comment: How does this help me orthogonalize M? That's really what I want to do. Sure, I could absorb them, but wouldn't that just give me M back?

Comment: Please rephrase your question, I quote "how can I transform my SVD decomposition so that the singular values equal the identity?"

Comment: Sorry, edited it. I realize what I asked was either not true, not helpful, or both. Hopefully the updated explains what I am after.

Comment: Ok I think I see what you're after. If the rank of the column space is k then the first k columns of U are orthonormal vectors spanning the column space, which is the same as Q. So Q and U are very similar, but not necessarily the same. But to me they are "psychologically equivalent", in a way :). Remember though,  QR and SVD do not always have unique decompositions, so this complicates the answer.

Comment: But I don't know if one can rewrite an SVD decomposition such that U = Q, or if one can tweak the algorithm of SVD so that it finds a solution such that U = Q, sorry. But if I may ask, why do you need to do this? I can't think, with my limited imagination, what this would be useful for.

Comment: Curiousity, mainly! I can't see a need to do it, but am learning about how different matrix decompositions are related.